# Python pandas : pivot_table simple string aggregation and sort

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to achieve something with pandas which is very straightforward to do in Excel PivotTable:

[image: goal]

[image: excel_pivot]

[image: sort]

From what I've seen, the following code seems logic, but it doesn't work. And bottom line I'm wondering how complex can it get to implement such a simple aggregation. Any suggestions?

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(data=df,
           aggfunc = 'count',
           index = ["root_name", "rca"],
           values = ["rca"],
           margins = True).sort_values(['rca'], 
           ascending=[False])
```

EDIT: Sample input data and output

```
    try: from io import StringIO  # Python 3
except: from StringIO import StringIO  # Python 2

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = u"""root_name;rca
Mobile Voice;mib manual manipulation
Mobile Voice;mib manual manipulation
Internet;dq
Mobile Voice;defect
Internet;mnp
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;defect
Mobile Voice;ceased in mib before dqt run
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;ceased in mib before dqt run
Internet;dq
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;dq
Mobile Voice;no dq
Mobile Voice;no dq
Mobile Voice;asset ceased while order was pending
Internet;dq
Mobile Voice;no dq
Internet;mnp
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;salto replication delay
Mobile Voice;provide order created dq
Internet;mnp
Mobile Voice;mib manual manipulation
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;ceased in mib before dqt run
Mobile Voice;mnp
Mobile Voice;mib manual manipulation
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=';', usecols= ['root_name', 'rca'], engine='python')

pt = pd.pivot_table(data=df,
               aggfunc = 'count',
               index = ["root_name", "rca"],
               values = ["rca"],
               margins = True)


print (pt.sort_values(['rca'], 
               ascending=[False]))
```

Result:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(Mobile Voice, salto replication delay), (Mobile Voice, provide order created dq), (Mobile Voice, no dq), (Internet, mnp), (Mobile Voice, mnp), (Mobile Voice, mib manual manipulation), (Internet, dq), (Mobile Voice, dq), (Mobile Voice, defect), (Mobile Voice, ceased in mib before dqt run), (Mobile Voice, asset ceased while order was pending), (All, )]

Comment: you should provide a minimal example (input+output) as **text**

Comment: @mozway Thanks for you comment, just added a simple test case

Comment: and what are the expected logic and output?

Comment: The expected output is what's depicted on the first Excel pivot table image. In pandas terms, a multi-index on root_name and rca and respective totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add 'count' field to your data frame and then just group by using count() method:

```
df['count'] = 1
df.groupby(by=['root_name', 'rca']).count().sort_index('rca')
```

Output:

```
                                                   count
root_name    rca                                        
Internet     dq                                        3
             mnp                                       3
Mobile Voice asset ceased while order was pending      1
             ceased in mib before dqt run              3
             defect                                    2
             dq                                        1
             mib manual manipulation                   4
             mnp                                       7
             no dq                                     3
             provide order created dq                  1
             salto replication delay                   1
```

Small tweak to reproduce excel results, by adding "root_name" sum field:

```
grouped_sum = df.groupby(by='root_name').sum().reset_index(level=[0])
grouped = df.merge(grouped_sum, how='left', on='root_name')
grouped.rename(columns={'count_x': 'count', 'count_y': 'sum'}, inplace=True)
grouped
       root_name                                   rca  count  sum
0   Mobile Voice               mib manual manipulation      1   23
1   Mobile Voice               mib manual manipulation      1   23
2       Internet                                    dq      1    6

pd.pivot_table(
           data=grouped,
           aggfunc=['count'],
           index=[ "root_name", "sum", "rca"],
           values=["count"],
           margins=True).sort_values(["sum", 'root_name', 'rca'], 
           ascending=[False, True, True]
)
```

Output:

```
                                                      count
                                                      count
root_name    sum rca                                       
All                                                      29
Mobile Voice 23  asset ceased while order was pending     1
                 ceased in mib before dqt run             3
                 defect                                   2
                 dq                                       1
                 mib manual manipulation                  4
                 mnp                                      7
                 no dq                                    3
                 provide order created dq                 1
                 salto replication delay                  1
Internet     6   dq                                       3
                 mnp                                      3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's indeed closer to what I'm trying to get. But still, "Mobile Voice" as first level, contains more "rca" than "Internet". How can I sort based on the first level, so in this case, "Mobile Voice" appears first and having all it's rca's right below?

Comment: Does it mean you need 'totals' for each root_name and then you need to apply sorting based on that as well?

Comment: Correct, and the sorting should be based on the rca count of each root_name. E.g. "Mobile  Voice" has 50 rca in total, should appear first with his rca right bellow. Then "Internet" has 35, should appear next. "Some other roor_name" has 20 rca, appears next and so on. Basically same has shown in Excel Pivot table.

Comment: You can achieve it by calculating the sums of "root_name" field and merging it to the main data frame. I have edited the solution.

Comment: Got it, that's it! Thanks a lot for your help! Still my concern turns out to be true, it isn't that intuitive to reproduce with pandas the simplest Excel Pivot table.